# Не получается разделить строку методом split

Tags: c#, winforms, строки

Необходимо записать строку в textbox со словами от 1 до 5 прописных букв, каждое слово надо разделить минимум 1 пробелом и все должно работать с KeyPressEventArgs. В итоге попробовав поставить split и вернув в textbox текст продолжает идти без пробелов. Нужна помощь в том как ограничив ввод только прописными буквами можно было мануально вставлять пробелы.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs check)
{
    string text = (sender as TextBox).Text;

    if (!(char.IsUpper(check.KeyChar)))
        check.KeyChar = '\0';
    else if (text.Length % 5 == 0)
    {
        string[] split = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            textBox1.Text = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мдя, ну а почему бы просто в цикле не брать по одному символу из text, отсчитывать количество символов и на каждом пятом перед добавлением символа из text в textBox1.Text добавлять пробел. Это самое логичное решения для зеленого начинающего программера.

Comment: Да, и все же есть смысл хоть что-нить прочесть про методы класса string и в частности, метод Split(). Кстати, Вам совсем не нужна строка text - Вы можете в textBox1.Text добавлять check.KeyChar, отсчитывая количество принятых символов, и после каждого пятого вставлять туда пробел.

Comment: не совсем понятно что вы хотите на выходе получить, если туже строку, то вам надо добавить пробел, а если после каждого пятого символа(в том числе с пробелом или без него), то это другое, так что вы хотите на выходе получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то Вам надо после каждого пятого символа, если это не пробел добавлять пробел.
Split немного не про то.
Набросал вариант, который возможно устроит.
В условии добавил проверку на пробел, если слова не обязательно по 5 символов, то его запрещать тоже не стоит.
А принцип простой, ищете последний пробел, и если разница между его индексом и длиной строки больше 5, то добавляете пробел и смещаете каретку в конец.
Правда этот вариант не сработает в случае внесения данных в середину текста.

```
    private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar))&&(e.KeyChar != ' ' ))
            e.KeyChar = '\0';
        else
        {
            int index = textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(' ');
            if (textBox1.Text.Length - index > 5)
            {
                textBox1.Text += " ";
                textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, друг рассказывал, что реализовал этот метод через split. У меня ничего не получалось с ним и мне казалось, что использование LastIndexOf с сохранением пробела не решит проблему, если у него сработал при приблизительно похожем задании split, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Методом Split в данном случае из введенного текста можно получить массив слов.